# What is the best way to transform many small files to Delta table in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks, delta-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have many small CSV files for each day with same schema. I would like to merge all of these files to a Delta table. Ideally it should only take the new files in the folder and append it to the Delta table.

Unfortunately I'm not sure how, firstly, append all the small files to a Delta table the best way using pyspark and secondly how to only chose the newest CSV files in the folder. Can someone understanding the bronze, silver, gold layers of delta lake help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have not mentioned I am assuming that you will running this ingestion databricks (DBR 9.1+) and files are in azure delta lake gen 2 based on your tags

So first about ingesting many small files there is not much optimization that we can do while ingesting only after loading it we can combine or do something with it , next is for keeping track of files in folder and loading only new files from it we can use `Auto Loader` from databricks as below

```
spark.readStream
                  .format("cloudFiles")
                  .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")
                  .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", f"{some_local_path}")
                  .option("cloudFiles.schemaHints", "date DATE, user_info.dob DATE, purchase_options MAP<STRING,STRING>, time TIMESTAMP")
                  .load("path_to_your_files")
                  .writeStream
                  .option("checkpointLocation", f"{some_local_path2}")
                  .trigger(availableNow=True)
                  .table("your_delta_table_name")
```

Here using format cloudfiles we are using Auto loader functionality of databricks , as it supports schema evolution of files we need to mention some schemalocation, schema hints helps in determining default schema of files but schema is not restricted to it while checkpoint location is location where it will keep track of files which are already processed and files which are newly added to be processed

Note that this works based on file names so for example if you had 10 files first day you rand code and 12 files the next day it will check the names of files in checkpoint location and load only 2 files next time whose name is not in the list

Sample Auto loader notebook by databricks [here](https://docs.databricks.com/ingestion/auto-loader/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm currently using Synapse Analytics. Is there a way to do this in Synapse, since I'm not sure if there is a Autoloader or do I need a specific Databricks instance?

Comment: In synapse Analytics there is no auto loader so you can give a look to this [article](https://sqlofthenorth.blog/2021/11/18/change-data-capture-upsert-patterns-with-azure-synapse-analytics-and-databricks/) else what I had used earlier was maintaining a metadata table with while names processed and next time only those files are picked from folder whose name is not present in the said metadata table

Comment: Hi, I would like to further ask, how would you do data transformation then? Is it possible to combine Autoloader with the transformation step, like renaming table columns, change format of data from string to float etc.?

Comment: We followed kind of multi-hop architecture of databricks where we didn't transform anything in the first table loaded by autoloader and named it as raw with all values untouched and then transformed /cleansed data in another layer/table and call it as cleansed as for your question if its possible or not then its certainly possible to do those tasks in by chaining transformations in incoming df and then writing data

Comment: Thanks you for your fast reply. So as I understand you used Autoloader to load raw data as delta Format to bronze as one table, afterwards cleaned/transformed the data to silver layer?

Comment: Yes correct....